# What's wrong with this implode?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Just playing around with different functions, trying to learn as much abut them as I can before I move forward with my self study. Could someone please explain what's going on below? (Please ignore that the query isn't prepared or at all secure)

```
  $query = "SELECT userid FROM users_groups_memberships WHERE groupid='".$GroupID."'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($relationshipQuery);

       while($row = $relationshipResult->fetch_row()) {
             $existingMembers[]=$row;
       }

  $memberString = implode(', ', $existingMembers);
  echo $memberString;
```

I'm expecting a comma separated list of numbers like `1, 4, 6, 88, 100` but I'm actually getting `Array, Array, Array, Array, Array`.

I know this is dead simple because I've had `array` returned before and I remember it was because I was doing something stupiud, I just don't remember what!

I'm actually trying to see if another variables value is present in `$existingMembers` using `in_array` but I get 0 always, probably because the values are `array` there too.

Thanks in advance for any support :)

Comment: Try this, `$existingMembers[] = $row['userid'];`

Comment: I've added a breakdown of the `mysqli` `fetch_*` commands below for your reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is an array of the columns returned from the query.

`print_r($row)` will show what your adding.

Try:

```
while($row = $relationshipResult->fetch_row()) {
    $existingMembers[]=$row['userid'];//Or $row[0] depending on the format of $row
}
```

Comment: That was a very fast 8+ answers! haha I tries this but only get commas returned, like: `,,,,`

Comment: @Arbiter Maybe try `$row[0]` instead. What do you see if you `print_r($row)`?

Comment: This is only true if you change [`fetch_row()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) to [`fetch_assoc()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 2):

Each row is an array and implode does not join in 2 dimensions.

If you want this to do the output you suggested try changing your statement in the loop to:

```
$existingMembers[] = $row['userid'];
```

Comment: The output suggests that `$row` is an array, but this would require it to be an object.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm posting this answer a little late, but the use cases for when to use the different `fetch_*` functions seems to be a little disjointed and unclear. I'll explore the solution based on your sample snippet and some possible alternatives:

### Solution

```
while($row = $relationshipResult->fetch_row()) {
    $existingMembers[]=$row[0];
}
```

Please review the documentation for [`fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php). `fetch_row()` returns a result row as an *enumerated array* (i.e. `$row[0]`, `$row[1]`, etc).

---

### Alternative Solutions

Dealing with an enumerated array may be confusing from time to time. There are a couple alternatives you can use to avoid the confusion of numbered indexes.

**Alternative 1:**

```
while($row = $relationshipResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $existingMembers[]=$row['userid'];
}
```

In this example, the result row is returned as an *associative array*. This makes the coding a bit cleaner and more understandable because it allows you to use the field names requested as the array indexes. In your example, the field name from your SQL query, `userid`, becomes the key in the associative array and can be accessed using the above notation.

For more information on this alternative, please see the [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

**Alternative 2:**

```
while($row = $relationshipResult->object()) {
    $existingMembers[]=$row->userid;
}
```

In this example, the result row is returned as an *object*. Again, this makes the coding a bit cleaner and more understandable because it allows you to use the field names requested as the object properties. In your example, the field name from your SQL query, `userid`, becomes the object property and can be accessed using the above notation.

For more information on this alternative, please see the [`fetch_object()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

---

### Summary

So just to recap, these are the specific use cases of the `fetch_*` functions associated with `mysqli_*`. The use cases for when to use the specific functions seemed a little unclear before. I hope this helps clear that up.

Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

try fetch_field() instead I think it will return the value of the field.
I think fetch_row is serving you array('userid'=>1)

Answer (score -1):

change

```
$existingMembers[]=$row;
```

to

```
$existingMembers[]=$row['userid];
```

Comment: `$row` is an array but it is not an associative array. `$row` is in fact an enumerated array. See [`fetch_row()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) and [`fetch_assoc()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for more details.